# Ordering in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

The URLs are not listed exactly the way I want them. URL-2 should follow URL-1. But, URL-10 and URL-11 are between them.

[image]

My bst file: [Link 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ymtp72ccixowf1l/tez.bst?dl=0)

Alternative link for bst file: [Link 2](http://www.filedropper.com/tez)

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{r1,
  title     = {},
  author    = {{URL-1}},
  year      = {2019},
  url       = {https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/missions/esa-eo-missions/ers/mission-summary},
  note      = {2 Ocak 2019}
}

@misc{r2,
  title     = {},
  author    = {{URL-2}},
  year      = {2019},
  url       = {https://www.dlr.de/dlr/en/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-10377/565_read-436/#/gallery/350},
  note      = {5 Ocak 2019}
}

@misc{r3,
  title     = {},
  author    = {{URL-3}},
  year      = {2019},
  url       = {http://global.jaxa.jp/projects/sat/alos/},
  note      = {5 Ocak 2019}
}

@misc{r10,
  title     = {},
  author    = {{URL-10}},
  year      = {2019},
  url       = {http://www.cosmo-skymed.it/en/index.htm},
  note      = {5 Ocak 2019}
}

@misc{r11,
  title     = {},
  author    = {{URL-11}},
  year      = {2018},
  url       = {https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-1-sar/acquisition-modes/interferometric-wide-swath},
  note      = {13 Kasım 2018}
}



\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{apacite}
%%% Same fonts for URL
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}} %
\usepackage{natbib}

%---------------------------
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} %
\urlstyle{same}


% BEGIN
\begin{document}

\sloppy %  working with the \usepackage[none]{hyphenat} code

% CHAPTER-------------

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\cite{r1}\\
\cite{r2}\\
\cite{r3}\\
\cite{r10}\\
\cite{r11}\\
%---------------------


%BIBLIOGRAPHY---------


\setlength{\bibsep}{1\itemsep}
\bibliographystyle{tez}
\bibliography{\jobname}

%.....................

\end{document}
```

Comment: please don't use external temporary links, you could have added the bst file inline, but it is listing the reference in alphabetical order of author, but you are (ab)using the author field with short names, the simplest would be to use names in the alphabetical order you want so use `URL-01` not `URL-1` so that `02` comes before `10`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I gave a link because I got a warning about character limit. Sorry about that. Due to the rules of writing the thesis, I cannot put a zero at the beginning of single digits. Is there any other way to solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Is the `tez.bst` bibliography style file available online somewhere. Two general comments: (1) If you're working with the `apacite` citation management package, you should really also be using the `apacite` bibliography style. (2) The `apacite` and `natbib` citation management packages are incompatible and shouldn't both be loaded.

Comment: Another general comment/question: What are you trying to achieve by executing both `\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}}` and, later in the preamble, `\urlstyle{same}`?

Comment: @Mico Because, normal text and link fonts are different in the bibliography.

Comment: the bib markup really doesn't make sense: it is as if you wanted a numeric style of bibliography but rather than use a numeric bib style you are giving each author a number as their name. I have seen many very weird "thesis rules" but it is hard to believe that they actually say that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David Carlisle has already pointed out in a comment, `URL-1` is followed, in the ASCII table, by `URL-10` and `URL-11`, *not* `URL-2` and `URL-3`.

There is a well-established device for overriding the default sorting order in a bibliography that's processed by BibTeX: prefix the actual author's name with a suitably chosen `\noopsort` directive. Here, `\noopsort` should be defined via

```
\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}
```

Then, modify the `author` field as follows:

```
author = {{\noopsort{URL10}}URL-10},
```

The `\noopsort` instruction does "nothing", as far as LaTeX is concerned. However, it serves to override the default sorting order while BibTeX is doing its thing, and that's exactly what's needed.

In the following example, note the five `\noopsort` statements. I've had to make some changes to your code, as (a) I don't have access to the `tez` bibliography style and (b) loading both the `apacite` and the `natbib` package is a mistake. I've chosen to proceed by loading the `natbib` citation management package and employing the `plainnat` bibliography style. You are, of course, free to modify these changes.

[image]

A final comment: I think it's a mistake -- not a syntactic mistake, but a mistake in terms of content -- to leave off the `title` fields. The first and foremost point of a bibliography is to inform readers. I really don't understand why you don't write `title  = {{ERS} Mission Summary},` for the `r1` entry, etc.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@preamble{ "\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}" } % <-- new
@misc{r1,
  title  = {},
  author = {{\noopsort{URL01}}URL-1},
  year   = {2019},
  url    = {https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/missions/esa-eo-missions/ers/mission-summary},
  note   = {2 Ocak 2019}
}
@misc{r2,
  title  = {},
  author = {{\noopsort{URL02}}URL-2},
  year   = {2019},
  url    = {https://www.dlr.de/dlr/en/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-10377/565_read-436/#/gallery/350},
  note   = {5 Ocak 2019}
}
@misc{r3,
  title  = {},
  author = {{\noopsort{URL03}}URL-3},
  year   = {2019},
  url    = {http://global.jaxa.jp/projects/sat/alos/},
  note   = {5 Ocak 2019}
}
@misc{r10,
  title  = {},
  author = {{\noopsort{URL10}}URL-10},
  year   = {2019},
  url    = {http://www.cosmo-skymed.it/en/index.htm},
  note   = {5 Ocak 2019}
}
@misc{r11,
  title  = {},
  author = {{\noopsort{URL11}}URL-11},
  year   = {2018},
  url    = {https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-1-sar/acquisition-modes/interferometric-wide-swath},
  note   = {13 Kasım 2018}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
%\bibliographystyle{apacite}%{tez}
%%% Same fonts for URL
%\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}} %
%r

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or some other suitable bib style

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage[spaces,obeyspaces,hyphens]{xurl} % allow arbitrary line breaks in URL strings
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\sloppy %  working with the \usepackage[none]{hyphenat} code

\noindent
\cite{r1},
\cite{r2},
\cite{r3},
\cite{r10},
\cite{r11}

\setlength{\bibsep}{1\itemsep} % a dubious choice, in my opinion
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, \noopsort is working as I need. Thank you for other advices too.